# how to initialize a UI-component lazily

Tags: android, kotlin, lazy-initialization

Given the below example, how can I make lazy initialization of the TextView?
I attempted to do the initialization via **lateinit** and it worked, but it cant be done via lazy lambda function

**Activity**

```
    var mTextViewResult : TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.tvResult) }

    onCreate(...) {...}
```

Comment: @beigirad no any workarounds are needed if Kotlin Android Extensions are used.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `var` you should use `val`

```
val mTextViewResult : TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.tvResult) }
```

**DEPRECATED**
*Furthermore, if [kotlin android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) plugin is applied you do not have to call `findViewById()` too.*

In application level `build.gradle` add plugin for kotlin android extension

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions" // this plugin

...
```

Now you can use `tvResult` by importing your layout reference.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [DataBinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) to get easier initialization / use of your layout items.

Do as follow :

```
class YourClassActivity() {

    private var myTextView : TextView? = null    // At first, myTextView is null. Do not use it !

    private var viewModel = YourViewModel()

    override fun onCreate(...) {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityYourClassBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_your_class) // DataBinding will set your view
        binding.viewModel = yourViewModel

        // Init layout variables
        myTextView = binding.myTextView // If your TextView id is "my_text_view"

        /*
        ** Now you can use 'myTextView' in any of your function (not just onCreate).
        ** Just do not forget to put the nullable '?' mark after its name.
        */
        myTextView?.text = "Hello World"
        myTextView?.setOnClickListener { clear() }
    }

    private fun clear() {
        myTextView?.text = "" // You can use your variable anywhere you want !
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `lazy` with `var`. You can use  `var lateinit mTextViewResult : TextView` and mTextViewResult = findViewById(...) in onCreate <strike>or you can use [synthetics](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/) to access TextView by it's id defined in xml.</strike>